# UPDATE statement, COUNT with multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql

I have `TABLE1` as follows

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
+ date     + time     + course   + runner   + position +
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
+ 20120701 + 1200     + london   + aaa      +   1st    +
+ 20120701 + 1200     + london   + bbb      +   2nd    +
+ 20120701 + 1200     + london   + ccc      +   3rd    +
+ 20120701 + 1300     + london   + eee      +   1st    +
+ 20120701 + 1300     + london   + fff      +   2nd    +
+ 20120701 + 1400     + new york + ggg      +   1st    +
+ 20120701 + 1400     + new york + hhh      +   2nd    +
+ 20120702 + 2000     + london   + iii      +   1st    +
+ 20120702 + 2000     + london   + aaa      +   2nd    +
+ 20120702 + 2100     + new york + iii      +   1st    +
+ 20120702 + 2100     + new york + bbb      +   2nd    +
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

and a second table

```
+------+----------+------+--------+--------+-----+------+-------+
+idtbl2+ date     + time + course + runner + pos + link + total +
+------+----------+------+--------+--------+-----+------+-------+
+    1 + 20120701 + 1200 + london + aaa    + 1st + WWW  +       +
+    1 + 20120701 + 1200 + london + aaa    + 1st + XXX  +       +
+    1 + 20120701 + 1200 + london + aaa    + 1st + YYY  +       +
+    1 + 20120701 + 1200 + london + aaa    + 1st + XXX  +       +
+------+----------+------+--------+--------+-----+------+-------+
```

Basically I need to count the number of competitors (`RUNNER`) in a single event from `TABLE1` and update that count into the `TOTAL` field of the second table, `TABLE2`.

However, `TABLE1` is 8500 records in size, and `TABLE2` is 65,000 records in size.  When running the following query, it timesout and loses the MySQL connection.

```
update table2 b, table1 a set b.total = (select count(a.runner) from table1 where a.date = b.date AND a.time = b.time AND a.course = b.course AND a.position != 'DQ'  );
```

My limited understanding of JOINs leads me to believe that a JOIN will not help with the efficiency, so I am quite stuck.  Any ideas out there?

@MarkByers -

The JOIN creates a temporary table, a concatenation of both table, yes?  My thinking is that no matter what, I still have to compare four fields (date, time, course, runner) from one table against another.

I tried this, but it also times out:

Comment: Joins should be better than your current (very inefficient) query. Why do you think they will be slow?

Comment: The JOIN creates a temporary table, a concatenation of both table, yes? My thinking is that no matter what, I still have to compare four fields (date, time, course, runner) from one table against another.

Comment: "The JOIN creates a temporary table, a concatenation of both table, yes?" No - this is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove **table1** from the `update` clause, as you are already joining the tables (internally) with the nested *Select count...*. You are joining **table2** and **table1** without a `where` clause, the resulting product is so big to be processed that your engine times out.
2. Check the `where` clause in the nested `select`, I think you should filter the query by Runner, otherwise you are counting different Runners that have the same time, date, course, etc; unless that is what you want.

> ```
> update table2 b
> set b.total = (select count(a.runner) 
>       from table1 
>       where a.date = b.date 
>       AND a.time = b.time 
>       AND a.course = b.course 
>       AND a.position != 'DQ'  
>       AND b.runner = a.runner);
> ```

Comment: It still takes 90 seconds to complete, but it does complete.  I know this is highly inefficient, but until I progress away from the basics I am happy with this solution.  Your explanation in part 1) makes sense and I shall ensure I avoid such coding. ( I know I have done similar elsewhere, so I can look to cut down other processing times due to your explanation.)  As for your filter suggestion, I actually do want the same value next to each `RUNNER`.  Thanks again.